# Android Studio, define a JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I saw a video on Youtube for enhancing the performance of Android Studio. I did and now I can't launch my Android Studio. Now it gives an error saying that "If you already have a 64-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Settings Environment Variables. Failed to create JVM. JVM Path C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre"

[image]

I searched the whole internet and tried every solution mentioned but I still get the "define JAVA_HOME variable" error. I tried both completely uninstalling the Android Studio with all files and related folders manually deleted but still get this error and Android Studio just won't simply run. I have exams in a few days and I have a lot to practice.

Edit:

[image]

I just removed the JAVA_HOME. I have both the JDK and JVM installed. I am just uninstalling and installing Android Studio at the moment.

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: What have you got in your Environment Variables at the moment? Did you install just Android Studio by itself or the JDK first, then Android Studio separately?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, so I found an answer after spending 5 hours fixing\setting Environment Variables (JAVA_HOME), uninstalling and reinstalling both the JDK and Android Studio.

The answer was simple. For any version of Android Studio that is >version 4.0, you need to remove the "studio.exe.vmoptions" or "studio64.exe.vmoptions" (depending on your system) from the directory "C:\Users{Your Username}\AppData\Roaming\Google{Android Studio Version}".

Comment: helped after i removed from AppData AND C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to remove Java_Home?
[Java_Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKWHy.png)
Then try to start Android Studio.
If there is still error, Try to uninstall JDK from programs.

It would be nice if you share some screenshots of "Environment Variables".

Did you tried all from here ? [Problems setting the JAVA_HOME variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204602/problems-setting-the-java-home-variable)

Comment: I just edited my question. Please check that now and see what is up. I removed JAVA_HOME after your comment. Still no luck in starting Android Studio.

Comment: Can you double click "Path" (System variables) and take screenshot?

Comment: And yes, I have tried all the solutions from literally every link I found. Videos, Stackoverflow, other websites, etc.

Comment: How am I still getting this error even after I uninstalled the Android Studio and all it's files?

Should I completely remove JDK, JVM, as well as Android Studio and install everything again and see if it works?
Will it work?

Comment: Okay, I am still getting that error no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this. Create JAVA_HOME and enter the value or your bin directory.**

[image: Try This]

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when updating android studio to version 4.2.1 and I try to solve it using Isaac answer suggestion but I don't find these files
the solution which works with me is writing `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre` in the Windows terminal and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450229/4979652) the alternative commands for other operating systems